# Find equation from sine graph with different amplitude and period

Tags: calculus

I am asked to find the equation from the following graph:

[image: graph]

Am I correct in saying the answer is:

${3 \sin(3x)}$ because the amplitude is 3 and the curve repeats itself after${2 \pi 3}$ and using ${\text{Period} = {2\pi\over b}}$

Comment: Yes, nice work.

Comment: You should be aware that the question itself -- asking for "the equation" that corresponds to the graph -- doesn't make sense: there are *infinitely many* functions that have this graph. Another such function is $3\sin(3(x-2\pi))$. Another is $-3\cos(3(x-\pi/2))$. What the instructor meant to ask is for *a* function with this graph (assuming the graph extends periodically to the left and the right). Your answer is indeed one such function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct

$$-1\leq\sin \theta\leq 1$$

And

$$\color{blue}{-3}\leq\color{blue}3\sin \theta\leq \color{blue}3$$

here we have

${\text{Period} = {2\pi\over 3}}$

and $\text{Period=one cycle}$ it is known that $\sin$ cycle is $2\pi$

$\frac{2\pi}{3}\cdot t=2\pi$ therfore $t=3$

So the function is $3\sin(3x)$.